# edit the dynamic data from repeat region in php

Tags: edit, recordset

I want to edit a record set based on FileNo, which is linked with another table with fileno as the linking fields.  I am here providing the two set of codes, one is working and other is giving the code error.

Working code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM casedt WHERE AdvUser= '".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."' &&  FileNo = $fileno ";
$result= mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
#$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Adv User</th><th>File No.</th><th>Next Dt</th><th>Comments</th><th></th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["AdvUser"]."</td><td>".$row["FileNo"]."</td><td>".$row["NextDt"]."</td><td>".$row["Comments"]."</td></tr>";   

    }
```

Non-working code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM casedt WHERE AdvUser= '".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."' &&  FileNo = $fileno ";
$result= mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
#$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Adv User</th><th>File No.</th><th>Next Dt</th><th>Comments</th><th></th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["AdvUser"]."</td><td>".$row["FileNo"]."</td><td>".$row["NextDt"]."</td><td>".$row["Comments"]."</td><td><a href=EditDate.php?recordID= .$row['FileNo'] Edit</a></td</td></tr>";   

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: There is error in php code

Comment: in your While bloc, you have :  Edit</a></td</td></tr>"; you have to delete </td

Comment: after removing the extra </td>, the position remain same: "syntax error"

Comment: Working Code: {
        echo "</td><td>".$row["FileNo"]."</td><td>".$row["NextDt"]."</td><td>".$row["Comments"]."</td><td><a href=EditDate.php?recordID= $row['FileNo'] Edit</a></td><td>Delete</td></tr>"  ; 

 }

Non-Working:
{
        echo "</td><td>".$row["FileNo"]."</td><td>".$row["NextDt"]."</td><td>".$row["Comments"]."</td><td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>"  ; 

 }